# Ubuntu Server 2 NICs, one for UDP traffic, the other one for internet

Tags: linux-networking, udp

I've an Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS with two nic cards. I need to setup them in a way that I listen only UDP traffic on one nic card and on the other one I have internet traffic.

I need this, because I process videos received from encoders from an UDP address and want to push the video as HLS (TCP) through another nic card.

Comment: Is your requirement for both inbound and outbound traffic? meaning inbound and outbound UDP will only go through the UDP interface? and the same for the TCP interface?

Comment: yes, that is what I need.

Comment: Is there a special reason, that you can't just assign two different IPs to your 2 NICs and seperate the traffic this way? If you can it's trivial to block any traffic other then TCP on NIC 1 and UDP on NIC 2...

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought we can do this with firewalld, and maybe a few rich rules to 'route' the traffic. But that idea turned messy quickly. You're going to need something that will understand the transport protocol before it hits your server.

My next idea was a load-balancer, and of course, HAProxy came to mind first; turns out HAProxy doesn't do UDP. But LVS does! It looks plausible. Give it a read: http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/